# How to connect Adempiere (or any PostGreSQL) to SSRS 2012 Express?

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services, ssms

Has anyone connected Adempiere (ERP) (or any PostGreSQL db) to SQL Server 2012 Express?

There used to be an IT manager to help me out with this, but now i'm left alone with this.

I downloaded the free Sql Server 2012 Express and wanted to use the SSRS for Adempiere. It seems its running on the SQL Server 2010 for SSRS.

I have already added the ODBC Data Sources for 32 Bit. My computer is using 64bit, is there any incompatibility? I'm not sure if my server is 32 or 64bit.

I've tried following the instructions on http://postgresblog.blogspot.com/ but to no avail.

I already have Crystal Report running, so i'm sure its possible to run 3rd party software for Adempiere.

Anyone knows how i can use SSRS for Adempiere? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Express edition, if you're trying to connect to any Data Source other than an database on the same SQL Server instance it won't work.

See [Features Supported by Reporting Services in SQL Server Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

From that article:

> Report data sources must be SQL Server relational databases that run
>   locally in SQL Server Express.

Also:

> Analysis Services, Oracle, XML, SAP, SQL Server Integration Services
>   (SSIS), OLE DB, and ODBC data sources are not supported.

You're going to need a different edition to connect to an ODBC Data Source.

Comment: Thanks, i will try another edition then and see whether it works

Comment: Just wondering, I have my ERP running on the server (i'm presuming since everybody has access to it). Do i still need to install the database engine for SQL Server 2012 in order to use SSRS? What do i need to install?

Comment: You will need SSRS and the database engine as SSRS needs two SQL Server databases to store its metadata and working information. However SSRS and the database engine don't have to be on the same machine, SSRS just needs to be able to access a SQL Server database engine instance. If you need more information than this it would be best to ask a new, separate question.